# Export Shape Key Animation without Geometry

Tags: animation, export, shape-keys, .fbx

I was wondering if there is a chance to export a shape key animation from blender (as .fbx) without actually exporting the mesh.

The reason why I am asking is, I want to use and import that animation in Unity. The animation will be applied onto the already imported model with the same poly order. However I don't want to export the same geometry over and over again with each animation fbx I create. It is very redundant and unnecessarily blows up my projects filesize.

Any ideas are welcome, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not with any existing exporter that I know of.  Without the mesh, the animation simply consists of keyframes of the various Shape Keys' `Value` setting.  You could write an exporter to export the F-curves, but then you'd be faced with the problem of the importer, in your case Unity, knowing how to associate the F-curves with the new mesh -- and you would only have the value settings, and no mesh delta information.

Comment: thanks for your answer. the problem you mentioned is no problem actually. I export my character once, including the rig and all shape keys. each animation that will have f-curves for the rig and shape keys will be imported individually and applied to the already importer character. so having obly the f-curves for the shape key index is what I need and what will work in unity. I tested this before and it works. Only problem is having redundant geometry with each animation I export. and the reason fir that are the shape keys.

Comment: So having a custom exporter would be the solution I guess…